# How can I get image resizing via Saxon-JS?

Tags: javascript, html, xslt, saxon, saxon-js

I have a following HTML file that tests image resizing via JavaScript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">
<html>
   <head>
        <title>Image Test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            img.img-responsive {
                display: block;
                max-width: 100%;
                height: auto;
            }
            img.fig{
                display: block;
                max-width: 10000px;
                height: auto;
            }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
        <h2>Image Test</h2>
        <p>Image: width="100%"</p>
        <img class="img-responsive" alt="fig" src="img/fig.jpg"/>
        <script>
            window.addEventListener('load', function() {
                 [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName("img-responsive"),function(elem){
                    elem.addEventListener('click',toggleClassName.bind(null,elem, "fig"));
                });
            })
            /* Toggle specified class name
               elem: DOMElement
               className: class name
            */
            function toggleClassName(elem, className){
                var s = ' ' + className;
                if (elem.className.indexOf(className) === -1){
                    elem.className += s ;
                    return true;
                }else{
                    elem.className = elem.className.replace( s , '' );
                    return false;
                }
            }
        </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

This works fine. So now I want do the same thing via Saxon-JS using XSLT stylesheet. My first stylesheet is as follows:

[handle-click.xsl]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:ixsl="http://saxonica.com/ns/interactiveXSLT"
    extension-element-prefixes="ixsl"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">
    <xsl:template match="img[contains(@class,'img-responsive')]" mode="ixsl:onclick">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(@class,'fig')">
                <ixsl:set-style name="class" select="replace(@class,' fig','')"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <ixsl:set-style name="class" select="concat(@class,' fig')"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have compiled this stylesheet via oXygen 19.1 and generated handle-click.sef file. Then I modified the above HTML to use Saxon-JS library.

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">
<html>
   <head>
        <title>Image Test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            img.img-responsive {
                display: block;
                max-width: 100%;
                height: auto;
            }
            img.fig{
                display: block;
                max-width: 10000px;
                height: auto;
            }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
        <h2>Image Test</h2>
        <p>Image: width="100%"</p>
        <img class="img-responsive" alt="fig" src="img/fig.jpg"/>
        <script>
            window.addEventListener('load', function() {
                SaxonJS.transform({
                stylesheetLocation: "handle-click.sef.xml"
                });
            })
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/SaxonJS.min.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

However nothing happened by clicking the image. What is wrong with this HTML file (or stylesheet)?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you try to use `ixsl:set-style` to manipulate the class of an element, I would think you should use the DOM `classList` property of the element and use its `toggle` method.

I am also not sure you can call the `transform` method solely with a stylesheet.

Below you can find a sample I have tested (locally with Firefox) with Saxon-JS 1.0.2 that inserts a `div` (didn't want to use an image) and calls its `classList` `toggle` method, providing the CSS class name you want to toggle as the argument:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
        <title>Saxon-JS test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            div.responsive {
                border: 5px solid green;
                display: block;
                max-width: 100%;
                height: auto;
            }
            div.fig{
                border: 10px solid yellow;
            }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
        <h2>Saxon-JS test</h2>
        <section id="saxon-target"></section>
        <script>
            window.addEventListener('load', function() {
                SaxonJS.transform({
                stylesheetLocation: "test2017122001.sef.xsl",
                initialTemplate: "Q{http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform}initial-template"
                });
            })
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Saxon-JS-1.0.2/SaxonJS.min.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

XSLT is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:ixsl="http://saxonica.com/ns/interactiveXSLT"
    extension-element-prefixes="ixsl"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
      <xsl:result-document href="#saxon-target">
         <div class="responsive">This is a test.</div>
      </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="div[contains(@class,'responsive')]" mode="ixsl:onclick">
        <xsl:sequence select="ixsl:call(ixsl:get(., 'classList'), 'toggle', ['fig'])[current-date() lt xs:date('2000-01-01')]"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The CSS style changes (e.g. border color and width change) are applied when the `div` is clicked so that should help you set up similar code for the img whose classList you want to manipulate.

Example is now also online at https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/2017/test2017122001.html and works there with current versions of Edge, IE, Chrome and Firefox on Windows 10.